# ¿Por qué se reinician los id?

Tags: java, mysql, combobox

Buenas tardes tengo un combo box de productos que se carga cuando se selecciona el combo de tipos de productos , ese íd del combo de productos lo uso para pintar unos paneles,mi problema es que cada vez que se selecciona un tipo y los vuelve a cargar reinicia los íd no toma los de la base de datos

Esta es mi clase de productos:

```
   private int id;
    private String nombre;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public Vector<Productos> MostrarProductos(Integer idtipoproducto) {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Conexion conn = new Conexion();
        Connection con = conn.getConnection();
        Vector<Productos> datos = new Vector<Productos>();
        Productos dat = null;

        try {
            String sql = "SELECT Id_Producto,Nombre FROM c_productos WHERE Id_tipoproducto =" + idtipoproducto;
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            dat = new Productos();
            dat.setId(0);
            dat.setNombre("seleccione una opción");
            datos.add(dat);

            while (rs.next()) {
                dat = new Productos();
                dat.setId(rs.getInt("Id_Producto"));
                dat.setNombre(rs.getString("Nombre"));
                datos.add(dat);
            }
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        return datos;
    }
}
```

Aquí cargo los datos al combo:

```
private void CBTipoProductoItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                
    if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        TipodeProductos est;
        est = (TipodeProductos) CBTipoProducto.getSelectedItem();
        Productos num = new Productos();
        DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(num.MostrarProductos(est.getId()));
        CBProductos.setModel(model);
    }
}
```

mi pregunta es ¿como puedo agregarle bien los id al combo box?

Comment: El reiniciar los id a q t refieres?? A q los pone en 0?

Comment: me refiero a que si elijo el tipo de producto de liquido empiezan bien del 1 al 65 pero si cambias el tipo de producto por el dos o el tres estos se reinician del 1 asta el total de ese tipo cuando tendría que seguir el 66 ,67 etc

Comment: Debuguea para ver q ID de tipo de producto esta tomando la funcion. Ademas creo q los ID de los productos no deben ser consecutivos pero ya eso es cosa de como tengas los datos en la base de datos. Lo otro es q no pones el codigo de como añades los datos al primer combobox al de tipo de producto.